# Granting privileges on a view

Tags: permissions, view, authorization

I'm reading *Database System Concept*, in a chapter about **authorization**, the book first says that:

> A user who creates a view does not necessarily receive all privileges
> on that view. She receives only those privileges that provide no
> additional authorization beyond those that she already had."

but in a section immediately follows it, it says that:

> The creator of an object (relation/view/role) holds all privileges on the object, including
> the privilege to grant privileges to others.

I don't know whether the creator of a view must holds all privileges on the view or not, because from first section I blockquoted, I think we **don't necessarily receive all privileges** on a view which we create, but from second section, it indicates the creator indeed **holds all privileges** on the view.

Comment: Which Database?

Comment: It doesn't specify which database, so I think it's describing a general trait of database.

Comment: What is the (full) title of the book? Who are the authors? Are they established authorities in the field they are talking about? You might be better off contacting the publisher / author and discussing this matter with them. It might be a conceptual error in the book.